# How to make 2 parts my website black and one part white with div

Tags: html, css, layout, formatting

So I have been struggling to figure out how I would go about making 2 parts my website black and one part white.

For Example you go on to the site and the top half is black then the middle half is white and then the bottom half is black.

How would I do this using CSS and HTML

I know for html I need to use div elements but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
}
.black{
  background:#000;
  height:33.33%;
  width:100%;
}
.white{
  background:#fff;
  height:33.33%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="black">black part</div>
  <div class="white">white part</div>
  <div class="black">black part</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:33%;
background-color:black;
}
#content{
width:100%;
height:33%;
background-color:white;
}
#footer{
width:100%;
height:33%;
background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Okay for my home page I want to use one image however when I use the background-size: cover;  and the no-repeat after the url link to imagine its blury and nasty. How do I change that?

Comment: it depends upon the resolution of the image. can you be a little bit more specific about your requirement like, where do you want the image to be?

Comment: I want the imagine to cover the whole website. It's for the landing page.

Comment: it depends completely upon the image resolution then. However you might try out this:background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/